# How to allow public access to one folder without prompt login on Synology NAS via WebDAV

Tags: nas, webdav, calendar.app

I want to share one .ics calendar file publicly with whoever has the WebDAV file path URL. They should be able to subscribe to this .ics in any calendar applications they desire (eg. Google Calendar, Outlook Calendar, etc.)

Synology NAS DSM is the latest version. (Therefore, WebDAV servers no longer support WebDAV Calendars.)

Currently, I am using WebDAV and making one sharing folder which allows guest/anonymous WebDAV login. The problem is the user is still required to manually enter "guest" or "anonymous" in the username field when it prompts to log in.

I also tried to use `https://anonymous:@[URL]` It works fine if the user copy and open this URL once directly. The problem is that some services (eg. iCal sync) require constant pulling updates from this location and still fail due to the login request popup.

Is there a way I can set this specific folder to be publicly accessible with no login prompts?

Thanks.